# Drawing picture on html canvas with JSInterop from Blazor

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, blazor, blazor-hybrid

I'm using the html canvas from inside Blazor hybrid using JSInterop.

So far it was working fine, but now I need to add a picture on the canvas and it is not working.

I have placed the picture in the wwwroot/Images/Image2.jpg folder.
In the JS file I have:

```
let canvasCtx;
const image = new Image();
image.src = 'Images/Image2.jpg';

function InitBgndImage1(chart) {
canvasCtx = chart.getContext("2d");

//canvasCtx.beginPath();
//canvasCtx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
//canvasCtx.stroke();
canvasCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);}
```

The function is called from the Blazor file as follows:

```
<div class="chart-container">
<canvas @ref="chartCanvas"></canvas>
```

@code {
ElementReference chartCanvas;

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("InitBgndImage1", chartCanvas);
}
```

}

The rectangle is drawn when not commented but the picture never displays.

What could be the reason?

Comment: You need to ensure your image has loaded before you can draw it. Check the `complete` property of the `image`, or add an `onload` event listener, or use an `ImageBitmap`.

Comment: Thank you Luke Vo for your quick and clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not due to Blazor but due to Javascript.

When you set `image.src = 'Images/Image2.jpg';`, the image is not actually loaded yet. You have to wait for it to load before drawing.

Try this:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const img = new Image();
  
  await new Promise(r => {
    img.onload = r;
    img.src = "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U";
  });
  
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
});
```

```html
<p>
  <button>Draw</button>
</p>

<canvas></canvas>
```

If you didn't wait, you can see it doesn't work as well (a cache may make it work the 2nd attempt):

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const img = new Image();  
  img.src = "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U";
  
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
});
```

```html
<p>
  <button>Draw</button>
</p>

<canvas></canvas>
```